# Remove Maillard freewheel

Tags: repair, hub, freewheel, french

I'm trying to open the freewheel from an old bike that I have, but I can't find how. I even searched for tutorials on the Internet but I can't find one that looks like mine (please see picture).

[image]

And I have an old tool that looks like a fit tool (see picture below), but the inner diameter is smaller than the outer diameter of that central part of the freewheel,  therefore I can't put it in.

[image: Removal tool]

I also found this tool (see picture below) like it would fit in there but I don't have it yet.

[image: Removal tool]

Can anyone help with this? Which tool do I need for this and, more Important, is it possible to open it with a hammer and a screwdriver?  And if so, which part should I try to open, the middle black cylinder or the yellow toothed one?

Thank you!

EDIT:
Mine looks very similar to this:
[image]
Re-iterate the question. Do I need to open the cylinder with the two circular holes or the inner one with the two notches, in order to detach the freewheel?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not going to find the freewheel remover for a reasonable price easily for this freewheel (and its probably going to be a 1-time use item). Though it probably doesn't hurt to ask around.

It looks like you cut the hub out of the wheel which was a *big* mistake -- it makes it [a lot harder](http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/wheels.php) to remove the freewheel from the hub.

Anyhow, you can follow the usual [destructive freewheel removal](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freewheel-destructive-removal) instructions (for when you don't need to reuse the freewheel and don't have the correct tools). Basically, you'll use a punch and a hammer to remove the bearing cone and then take things out as they fall out. Then, use a vise to remove the part of the freewheel attached to the body.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and link. I find it hard to compare that case from the link with mine. I can see that they have that two-notch cylinder, but it doesn't look like he deals with it in any way. In my case, I took the balls from the bearing out when I took the shaft out. 

I just hammered both parts (the yellow toothed one) and the two-notch cylinder clockwise and counterCW, but no movement. I don't know what else to do...

Comment: And it was indeed stupid to take it out from the wheel

Comment: Maybe a picture of where you are in the disassembly process would help.